# Slow loading code

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm new to jquery and I've created a set of navigation links that do several functions all in one click. It seems to take a long time to load the file and therefore a long time before the web page reacts to the links being clicked. Could this be because I have "scrollTo" jquery pluggin? I've attached an example of one of the links controls, all the links are the same with a few variations changing.

Is the problem the format of the code or the problem with the code itself?

```
   $(".releases").click(function(){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 3000, function(){ //returns to top of the page
        $("#content").load('content.html #releases'); //loads the content associated with the link
        $("#banner").stop().animate({
            'background-position-x' : '-700px',
            'background-position-y' : '-500px'}, //background image position change
            2000, function()
            {$.scrollTo("#content", 3000); //returns to the main page content
        });     
    });
});
```

Comment: At what point is it slow? Does it scroll to the top of the page quickly or hang? Does it slow down when loading the content.html? Why scroll to the top of the page then back to #content? Why not wait for it to load and go right to the content?

Comment: It's slow to react to the jquery in that the page loads, you click link with the ".releases" class and it won't react instantly but needs time for the jquery file to load. I want the user to click the link, the page to scroll down, if they click another link page returns to the top to complete the animation while the ajax loads and then returns to the page.

Comment: @JamesSeabrook Link to your website in order to debug there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is slow to load, I think the problem is with the code itself. It is trying to return to the top of the page before it loads the other information, if you are opening the page new it will be at the top and will take the 3 seconds you have allowed for the page to scroll back to the top.

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 3000, function(){
```

This is your problem, you need an if - else statement to over ride the initial scroll top if the page is already at the top.